# Log4J2 Factory Error when attempting to use SMTP Appender

Tags: java, email, logging, log4j2, smtpappender

Good afternoon,

When I attempt to use the SMTP Appender, I get an odd error in the console. The error appears to occur when the XML file is loaded, as it isn't logged via any output stream except stdout. The contents of the appender are as follows (and I have confirmed that the error is in this block of XML). I've removed our server information.

```
<SMTP name="Mailer">
    <Subject>[ERROR] (software name) on ${hostName} has thrown a fatal error</Subject>
    <To>(a valid email in the form of a@a.com)</To>
    <From>(a valid email in the form of a@a.com)</From>
    <SMTPHost>(The Internal IP address of a server in the form of 192.168.0.1)</SMTPHost>
    <SMTPPort>587</SMTPPort>
    <BufferSize>512</BufferSize>
</SMTP>
```

Whether or not it is referenced in a logger, I receive the following error immediately upon running the program and running getLogger from the log manager. I've removed a couple of the file names and replaced them with a rough description of what the file is doing at that point.

> 2015-05-19 19:08:18,812 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender for element SMTP. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:137)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:766)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:706)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:698)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:358)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:161)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:361)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:426)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:442)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:426)
>       at (Our Log Interface Class, which essentially just returns the log passed by the Apache log manager)
>       at (The global variable definition file, the first method to use getLogger)
>       at (The main method for our software, where the globals are loaded)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.mail.Session.setProtocolForAddress(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager$SMTPManagerFactory.createManager(SmtpManager.java:325)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager$SMTPManagerFactory.createManager(SmtpManager.java:299)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:71)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.getSMTPManager(SmtpManager.java:124)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.createAppender(SmtpAppender.java:142)
>       ... 21 more
>
> 2015-05-19 19:08:18,814 ERROR Null object returned for SMTP in Appenders.
>   2015-05-19 19:08:18,819 ERROR Unable to locate appender Mailer for logger fatalerror

The details of the configuration are correct (I know it's a valid IP, etc) - they worked in log4j 1. The error log tells me virtually nothing about the error, so I am hoping someone has heard of this before. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You need to change `${hostName}` to `${sys:hostName}`.

Comment: Good catch, but this wasn't our problem actually. It was the mail API the software was using hadn't been updated in years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the important line from your stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.mail.Session.setProtocolForAddress(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

The [`setProtocolForAddress` method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Session.html#setProtocolForAddress(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) has been part of JavaMail since version 1.4, so this suggests to me that you are using an old version of that JAR.  If you are, try upgrading to a later version.

Comment: Exactly what it was, thank you. I took it for granted that there was a mail function in our software and never thought to check when the last time the library was updated (hint: it wasn't)

Answer (score 0):

Note that log4j2 has many lookups, not just system properties. So you need to convert `${hostName}` to `${sys:hostName}`, and if you are using a lookup for the IP address, this may be the cause of the issue. (Try hardcoding all lookup values to exclude this possibility.)

Comment: It actually was an outdated JavaMail version, but thanks for the suggestion anyway!